# What's the easiest way to fill in the texture of this human face?

Tags: texturing

[image: face]

What is the easiest way to fill in this face? I tried to use the clone tool in texture but it just looks like a weird pattern on the back of her head. It doesn't have to look perfect just doesn't need all this empty space.

[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/phqzttum6py1pzq/face%20with%20body.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options that may help you:

1. if you have a photo from the side of the head you can project it on the model with the *Stencil* brush.
2. find a photo of a similar person and use this with the stencil brush
3. paint your own skin texture
4. combine method 1 or 2 with method 3. Use the *Mix* nodes to mix the textures. Additionally, you can bake an Ambient Occlusion/Cavity map in *Cycles* and mix it.
5. for a more realistic look, remove the highlights/specular and shadows from the image. Add a *Roughness*, and *Bump* map for pores. Sculpt in wrinkles with a *MultRes* modifier and bake a *Normal* map from it.

Here is a quick try:

[image: screenshot]

Use *Gimp* or another paint program

- remove the transparency (Alpha channel). The background turned (accidentally) blue in my attempt.
- copy and duplicate an area of skin that has almost no shadow and no strong highlights. Fill all the missing areas with it
- to get rid of the weird pattern that will be visible use a strong *Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur*. Use the selection to exclude the face!
- now everything looks more uniform but blurry. So add some *Filter > Noise > RGB Noise* and *HSV Noise* and blur it a little bit with *Filter > Blur > Median Blur*. Repeat these steps until you're happy

In Blender, load the image and use the *Clone* brush with about `0.5` strength to remove "seams" and bad transitions" and create nice-looking skin.

Highlights and shadows can be removed with the Blend Mode *Darken only* and *Lighten*. This works in paint programs as well as in Blender. Just pick a color that you want to match and use the paintbrush. Also, try different strength values for the brush.

For the ears, a stenciled or an UV-projected image helps a lot.

Comment: Can you send me that picture of the texture? I followed the instructions and this is what mine looks like https://imgur.com/a/xOA2Yw0

Comment: try this one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TAuorpmwJlTBHHNMJgEQpPaFrXYVdvHs/view?usp=sharing